# Optimization of a query on a table that represents a weak entity type

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, schema

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a while now, so I decided I'll try my luck here.
I have a very complex online shop DB structure (multiple shops in one database, hundreds of thousands of products) and I'm querying MySQL to return products from a specified category. Products are in a many-to-many (M:N) relationship to categories, so I have tables `product`, `category` and `product_category` (which stands for a weak entity type).

Table schemas are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `date_edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `visibility` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `main_slider` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bought` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `price_action` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `quantity_action` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `duration_action` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `new` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `type` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `origin_url` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin_price` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `origin_price_dph` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ratingcount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `facebook_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `salebot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `shop_supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_global_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prioritize` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `free_delivery` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_global_id_2` (`product_global_id`,`shop_id`),
  KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`),
  KEY `shop_supplier_id` (`shop_supplier_id`),
  KEY `product_global_id` (`product_global_id`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `quantity_action` (`quantity_action`),
  KEY `duration_action` (`duration_action`),
  KEY `main_slider` (`main_slider`),
  KEY `shop_id_2` (`shop_id`,`main_slider`),
  KEY `shop_id_3` (`shop_id`,`prioritize`),
  KEY `shop_id_4` (`shop_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `category` (`category_id`),
  KEY `product` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

And the query I'm using:

```
SELECT product.id, 
       product.name, 
       product.shop_supplier_id, 
       product.price_action, 
       product.quantity_action, 
       product.duration_action, 
       variant.id as variant_id, 
       IF(variant.price_default IS NULL, variant_global.price_vat, variant.price_default) as price_default, 
       variant.price_dph as price, 
       variant_global.delivery_date, 
       variant.value AS variant_name, 
       IF(product.type = 0, variant_global.voc_silver, variant.voc_dph) as voc_dph, 
       shop_supplier.text_available, 
       shop_supplier.text_unavailable, 
       IF(product.type = 0, variant_global.available = 1, variant.availability = 1) as avail, 
       variant.availability_type, 
       supplier.id as supplier_id, 
       variant_global.price_vat as price_default_ds, 
       product.type 
      FROM `product` 
      LEFT JOIN shop_supplier ON (`product`.`shop_supplier_id` = `shop_supplier`.`id`) 
      LEFT JOIN supplier ON (shop_supplier.supplier_id = `supplier`.`id`)      
      LEFT JOIN variant_global ON ((SELECT id FROM variant_global WHERE variant_global.product_global_id=product.product_global_id ORDER BY `available` DESC LIMIT 1) = `variant_global`.`id`) 
      LEFT JOIN product_global ON (variant_global.product_global_id = product_global.id) 
      LEFT JOIN image ON (`product`.`id` = `image`.`product_id`) 
      LEFT JOIN variant ON ((SELECT id FROM variant WHERE `product_id`=product.id ORDER BY `availability` DESC LIMIT 1) = `variant`.`id`) 
      LEFT JOIN product_category ON (`product`.`id` = `product_category`.`product_id`) 
        WHERE (product.shop_id=100000) 
          AND (product.visibility= 1) 
          AND (image.id IS NOT NULL) 
          AND (IF(product.type = 0, variant_global.available = 1, variant.availability = 1) = (CASE WHEN display_available = 1 AND display_unavailable = 1 THEN IF(product.type = 0, variant_global.available = 1, variant.availability = 1) WHEN display_available = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
          AND (variant_global.deleted IS NULL OR variant_global.deleted = 0) 
          AND (product_category.category_id= 5) 
     GROUP BY product.id 
     ORDER BY prioritize DESC, RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

The query is called multiple times on a single page for different categories and is really slow, I've tried all different keys and combinations and couldn't figure it out.

The EXPLAIN of the query outputs this:

```
+------+--------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table            | type   | possible_keys                                 | key                 | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | product_category | ref    | PRIMARY,category,product                      | PRIMARY             | 4       | const                               | 4264 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | product          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,shop_id,shop_id_2,shop_id_3,shop_id_4 | PRIMARY             | 4       | dropohs.product_category.product_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | shop_supplier    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY             | 4       | dropohs.product.shop_supplier_id    |    1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | supplier         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY             | 4       | dropohs.shop_supplier.supplier_id   |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | variant          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY             | 4       | func                                |    1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | image            | ref    | PRIMARY,product_id_2,product_id               | product_id_2        | 4       | dropohs.product_category.product_id |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | variant_global   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY             | 4       | func                                |    1 | Using where                                  |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | variant          | ref    | product_id,product_id_2                       | product_id_2        | 4       | dropohs.product.id                  |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | variant_global   | ref    | product_global_id,product_global_id_2         | product_global_id_2 | 4       | dropohs.product.product_global_id   |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
+------+--------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

If you need any further information or schemas of the other tables used in the query, let me know, but I omited them for now as I don't think they are the cause of the problem as all of them are properly using indexes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN image`  .. `AND (image.id IS NOT NULL)`. If you don't want products without images, then `INNER JOIN image` and leave out the `AND image.id ...` criteria. Same with `LEFT JOIN product_category`, if you want a not-null category in the `WHERE`, don't use a `LEFT JOIN`, `[INNER] JOIN` is what you are really requesting.

Ordering with `RAND()` is probably also a cause of slowness.

Your subqueries on `variant*` `availability`  should be things you try to use [window functions](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104) for in later MySQL versions.

Try to incorporate the all categories into the query and get the results once rather than many times.

Also maybe try to cache this query result out of the database so you don't need to do it as frequently.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights. I'll try to implement them. But I don't think I can incorporate all categories into one query (except maybe by using UNION, but that would probably not solve the problem) - let's say on homepage of the shop, there are user-defined banners and each banner shows random products from specific category and prioritizes products which are marked as `prioritize`.

Comment: Other concern with this that I have is - why is optimizer putting the `product_category` joined table at first position instead of `product` and thus not using the provided index properly? I would except that MySQL would select from product table first and then joining on the product_category table via INNER JOIN.

Comment: Good question. It should be selecting the table that reduced the number of rows that need to be examined (grossly oversimplified). I suspect a 5 in the category `WHERE` reduces the number of results that need to be searched in the product table hence it being first. You probably need a index on the product table that covers all of the criteria used in this query.

Comment: I tried all different combinations of keys but couldn't come up with one solving the problem here - most of the time EXPLAIN just told me the key was not even being used or only the leftmost part was used even tho I respected the proper order of columns in the index.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this construct.  It feels terribly inefficient; try to come up with a different way to achieve the intent:

```
LEFT JOIN v ON ( SELECT id FROM v ... ) = v.id
```

You have a number of redundant indexes.  Note these rules:

- A `PRIMARY KEY` is an `INDEX`.
- If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`.

Looking at

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `product_global_id_2` (`product_global_id`,`shop_id`),
INDEX(shop_id, ...),
INDEX(shop_id, ...),
INDEX(shop_id, ...),
KEY `product_global_id` (`product_global_id`),
```

I recommend

- Get rid of `id` (unless it is a `FOREIGN KEY` from some other table),
- `PRIMARY KEY(shop_id, product_global_id)` -- in that order
- Toss that `UNIQUE KEY` since it is now redundant.
- Change the last `KEY` (above) to be `(product_global_id, shop_id)` on the presumption that that pair, in that order, whas needed.
- *Consider* tossing all indexes starting with `shop_id` as being mostly redundant with the PK.  (Note:  The data is clustered with the PK, and my new PK makes looking for row(s) by `shop_id` more efficient.)
- Change the `GROUP BY` to match my PK.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you expect that the 'right' table may have rows missing.  Since the `EXPLAIN` *started* with the last table in the `LEFT JOIN` chain, I suspect *none* of the `LEFTs` are necessary.

Be aware that if some 'right' rows are missing, the `NULLs` will show up in the following expression.  This could lead to surprising results.

```
     AND  (IF(product.type = 0,
                  variant_global.available = 1,
                         variant.availability = 1) =
             (CASE WHEN     display_available = 1
                       AND  display_unavailable = 1
                       THEN IF(product.type = 0, variant_global.available = 1,
                                variant.availability = 1)
                   WHEN display_available = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
           )
```

In this

```
          AND (variant_global.deleted IS NULL
            OR variant_global.deleted = 0)
```

no index can be used.  It would be better to pick either `NULL` or `0` to mean "deleted" and stick with it.

Alas, I don't really see much hope.

A common performance trick for

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ..
    JOIN ..
    GROUP BY ..
    ORDER BY ..
    LIMIT ..
```

Is to do the `LIMIT`sooner:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT.. )
    JOIN ..
    -- GROUP BY ..  -- probably no longer needed
    ORDER BY ..     -- (yes, redundantly)
    -- LIMIT ..     -- not needed unless the `JOINs` inflate
```

That is try to get the 5 ids with as little running around the tables as possible, *then* the `JOIN(s)` will have only 5 rows to lookup.

Alas, I did not see how to do that 'derived' table (subquery) without doing nearly all the work.

Comment: I changed join types for product_category and image to `INNER` as the first answer in this thread suggests. Considering the `LEFT JOIN` for `variant` table, what I need is to join on the variant table but attempting to join available variants first, thus this is the construct we came up with and works (but probably not efficient).
Also `id` is a foreign key in other tables so I can't remove it as PK, the `shop_*` keys are used for other different queries we use - we always select products for specified shop and then further filter them by date etc., that's why we have multiple similar keys.

Comment: @PavelHodoval - How big are the tables?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: `product` table has ~136k rows and `product_category` has around 204k. And for the joined tables - `variant` ~360k, `variant_global` ~406k and `image` ~398k. The InnoDB pool size is set to 1G, which kinda surprised me as well - we are using MariaDB Galera Cluster and I am not really sure if it has something to do with the fact that this value is set so low for such big tables, I'm gonna have to ask our server admin.

Comment: @PavelHodoval - 1G?  How tiny is your server?  That's a reasonable size for 3GB of RAM.  Keep in mind that the buffer_pool is a "cache".  If you have a huge amount of data, but only rummage in one corner of it, 1G is fine.  If, on the other hand, you are scanning all the data all the time, 1GB of data would be too big for 1G of buffer_pool.

Comment: @PavelHodoval - Also, I added to my Answer.